# Variables are empty in toolchain file

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, toolchain

I try to use `MSVC` and `MSVC_VERSION` in toolchain file -

*cmake-toolchain-file.cmake*

```
message (STATUS "Toolchain MSVC=${MSVC} MSVC_VERSION=${MSVC_VERSION}")
```

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
message (STATUS "Project MSVC=${MSVC} MSVC_VERSION=${MSVC_VERSION}")
```

Output is

```
> cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/cmake-toolchain-file.cmake
-- Toolchain MSVC= MSVC_VERSION=
-- Project MSVC=1 MSVC_VERSION=1800
-- Bulding target for: windows-x86
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/test/build
```

Is it normal behavior that I get `MSVC` and `MSVC_VERSION` from toolchain file empty?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it normal behavior that I get MSVC and MSVC_VERSION from toolchain file empty?

Yes. Variables initialized after `project` command. This is where toolchain read also. Try to add some extra messages:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
message(STATUS "Before project: MSVC(${MSVC})")
project(Foo)
message(STATUS "After project: MSVC(${MSVC})")
```

Result:

```
-- Before project: MSVC()
-- Toolchain MSVC()
-- Toolchain MSVC()
...
-- After project: MSVC(1)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

So I guess you have one hidden question in mind:

> Is it confusing?

Yes, for the `Visual Studio` generators. Since usually you can set some critical stuff like path to compiler in toolchain it doesn't make sense to read compiler-related variables like `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` before toolchain processed, i.e. before `project` command. But when you set generator to `Visual Studio` your compiler is always `MSVC`. This gives you a hint for the workaround. Just check `CMAKE_GENERATOR` variable in toolchain instead of `MSVC_VERSION` (though this will not work for NMake generator of course):

```
if("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" STREQUAL "Visual Studio 12 2013")
  message("Toolchain: MSVC 1800")
endif()

if("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" STREQUAL "Visual Studio 9 2008")
  message("Toolchain: MSVC 1500")
endif()
```